# webpack tns run android --bundle fails with 'onNavigatingTo' of undefined

Tags: android, webpack, bundle, nativescript

My application runs fine when I run using `tns run android` but when I use `tns run android --bundle` then it gives me exception.Following is a stacktrace:

```
System.err: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onViewAttachedToWindow failed
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'onNavigatingTo' of undefined
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/com.travel/files/app/vendor.js, line: 32768, column: 36
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js.FrameBase._onNavigatingTo', file:'file:///data/data/co
m.travel/files/app/vendor.js', line: 32768, column: 37
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js.FrameBase.performNavigation', file:'file:///data/data/
com.travel/files/app/vendor.js', line: 32740, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js.FrameBase._processNextNavigationEntry', file:'file:///
data/data/com.travel/files/app/vendor.js', line: 32733, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js.Frame._processNextNavigationEntry', file:'file:///data/data/c
om.travel/files/app/vendor.js', line: 33206, column: 58
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js.Frame._onAttachedToWindow', file:'file:///data/data/com.trav
el/files/app/vendor.js', line: 33181, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'AttachListener.onViewAttachedToWindow', file:'file:///data/data/com.travel/files/app/vendor.js', line: 33
098, column: 27
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
```

Following is my package.json

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.travel",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"app/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.1",
    "nativescript-grid-view": "^4.1.1",
    "nativescript-purchase": "^2.0.5",
    "nativescript-social-share": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.6",
    "nativescript-ui-chart": "^3.9.1",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.6.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.18.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^5.0.2",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Can someone please guide me what's wrong here? Full source code can be found at https://github.com/rakeshgirase/NSWebpack

Comment: Must be something specific to your code / project, do you have a sample repo or playground example?

Comment: Can this be with my webpack.config.js? The webpack.config.js update instruction dont work on windows as given on https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/bundling-with-webpack. /node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs --deps
Usage. I will create a repo to replicate this issue.

Comment: Is it on only run bundle?

Comment: yes. tns run android runs fine its only bundle which gives the exception given above.

Comment: Added full source code to git at https://github.com/rakeshgirase/NSWebpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nativescript webpack analyzes statically all components that need to be loaded and to ease this process, that is why every page must end with "page". More details can be found at https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/issues/775 .